# Cannot get tensorflowjs model when using safari-core browser

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, safari, tensorflow.js

I want my web application to run some tensorflowjs and tflite models on the front end.

The related code is simple and the model will be successfully loaded when using chrome or firefox on Android or PC. I set my backend to print every file that sends to the front end to the command line to see if everything transfer smoothly.

However, when I am using ios browsers with Safari's core (Chrome for ios has the same core as Safari), everything can get instead of the tfjs model. My backend will not print the file of the tfjs model. The browser did not send a get message to get the model.

I paste my code of loading models and nodejs code that related to this part here. I just have no idea why only safari-core browsers will not load the model. I think maybe it is because it requires a more strict mime format but I do not know how to write it.

I think a possible reason for this is that the safari cannot load the module. Now, I found it will show an error says `unexpected identifier 'tf'`. I use this

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@3.8.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis@1.5.1/dist/tfjs-vis.umd.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./javascripts/model_init.js"></script>
```

to import my js code to initialize the tfjs model because I want the model on the client side.

I will really appreciate it if you know how to solve this issue.

model_init.js:

```
model.net = await tf.loadGraphModel('./models/web_model/model.json');
```

server.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
var querystring = require('querystring');
var url = require('url');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
// var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

// var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
var dir = __dirname;
var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript',
    json: 'application/json',
    bin: 'application/octet-stream',
    tflite: 'application/octet-stream'
};

app.use(express.static('public'));
//app.use(fileupload());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({limit : '50000kb'}));
app.use(express.raw({
    inflate: true,
    limit: '50000kb',
    type: 'application/octet-stream'
}));
app.use(favicon(path.join(dir, 'sources', 'favicon.ico')));
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    let prefix = '';
    var file;
    //console.log(req.path);
    file = path.join(dir, req.path.replace(/\/$/, '/index_mobile.html'));
    console.log(file);
    //console.log(typeof url.parse(req.url,true).query['StudyID']);
    if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
        return res.status(403).end('Forbidden');
    }
    var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
    s.on('open', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', type);
        s.pipe(res);
    });
    s.on('error', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(404).end('Not found');
    });
});
```

Comment: I found the reason. Only the latest Safari that turns on experimental features are able to run tfjs.

Comment: What are those experimental features?